# how can I import an multiple array into a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, import

How can I import an multiple array into a mysql database with php ?

The database I have created has only one table (jobs) and 3 Fields `(plz,ort,work)` later more fields, I want to run an cron job several times a day to get the database actual. The array comes from a other database witch I would like to import in my database.

**My array:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Code] => 0
    [Message] => 
    [Data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [plz] => 12345
                    [ort] => Testort
                    [work] => Schlosser
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [plz] => 12345
                    [ort] => Testort
                    [work] => Schlosser
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will

```
<?php
$stdObject = new stdClass();
$stdObject->data = array(
    array(
        "plz" => "12345",
        "ort" => "Testort",
        "work" => "Schlosser",
    ),
    array(
        "plz" => "12345",
        "ort" => "Testort",
        "work" => "Schlosser",
    )
);


// sql statement to insert data
$sql = "INSERT INTO job (plz,ort,work) VALUES :values";

// empty array to keep each row insertion
$values = array();

// makes following peaces
// ('12345', 'Testort', 'work')
// and push them into $values array.
foreach ($stdObject->data as $job) {
    $value .= "('" . $job['plz'] . "', '"
        . $job['ort'] . "', '"
        . $job['work'] . "')";
    $values[] = $value;
}

// convert values array to string
$values_string = implode(', ', $values);

// sql injection safe insertion
$pdo->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute(array(
    'values' => $values_string
));
```

Also for Pdo class usage you can see http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

I hope this helps.

Comment: THX, I have imported the first data :). But the last problem I have is my format of my array. With your way of writing it runs. But how do I get my array into "$stdObject->data"?? I have no idea. I post the hole script when it runs complete :)

Comment: simply do this: $stdObject->data = array(); // your array here.

Comment: or if you want add a array to data do this: $stdObject->data[] = array(); // your row_array here.

Comment: it does not run with my array shown in my project, can you help me?

Comment: now it is done :) thx to you. i have used the wrong array before

Comment: One more question, what can I do if one field contains (xml, html, ..) code. The import does not run than.

Comment: there is no problem with these kind of formats, can you explain with an example?

Comment: watch that they don't have sql keywords included.

Comment: is it possible to encode one field an later ti decode one in the array? or all?

Comment: yes you can use serialize() and unserialize() functions.

Comment: you can choose this answer to be correct if it helped you. thank you.

Comment: can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$str = serialize()` to save into the Datatbase and then use `unserialize($str)` to get it back.

Comment: sorry, but I am a beginner in programming. can you explain it to me with a coded example? this would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '';

foreach($data as $values){
    //because we all love foreaches
    $str .= "(";
    while(list($key, $value) = each($values)){
        if($key == 'work'){
            $str .= "'$value' ";
        } else {
            $str .= "'$value', ";
        }
    }
    $str .= ")";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO jobs VALUES" . $str . "";

echo $query;
```

Yes, I know this is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

the code below is running but only one field I can't import.

```
// and push them into $values array.
foreach ($myarray->Data as $job) {
    $value = "('"
        . $job['plz'] . "','"
        . $job['ort'] . "','"
        . $job['work'] . "')";
    $values[] = $value;
}

// convert values array to string
$values_string = implode(', ', $values);

// sql statement to insert data
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (plz,ort,work) VALUES $values_string";
```

There are mutch more fields but one of the contains such html Code. The user does copy from word in to there system.

```
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: normal"><SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Arial",sans-serif; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-language: DE'><SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Arial",sans-serif'><SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Arial",sans-serif'><SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Arial",sans-serif'> </P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: normal"><B style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Arial",sans-serif; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-language: DE'>Lorem ipsum dolor<?xml:namespace prefix = "o" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></SPAN></B></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: normal"><SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Arial",sans-serif; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-language: DE'><o:p> </o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt; LINE-HEIGHT: normal"><SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Arial",sans-serif; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-language: DE'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</SPAN></P>
```